# How do I delete the parent game objects attached to a script?

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

How do I delete the parent game objects attached to a script? You can see my code as an example, which is only removing the script on a game object. I am using Unity 5.5.2f1.

```
void destroySpawnersAndItems ()
{
    //FIX: It's deleting the script and not the complete object.
    var spawners = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(spawnerItem));
    var items = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(itemFood));

    foreach (var spawner in spawners)
    {
        Destroy(spawner);
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Destroy(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to write `Destroy(spawner.gameObject)`?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, your using a reference to the *components* in your call to `Destroy()`. This removes the specific *component*, but not the *game object* you have that component attached to.

The following variation to your script will remove the game object too which the component is attached to, and in doing so, will also remove that component, and any other component attached to the game object.

Note the inclusion `#if UNITY_EDITOR`. If you use this code via the Editor, Unity will complain that your not using `DestroyImmediate()`; however, this method is unsafe to use outside of the Editor, so we will tell the Editor to use `Destroy()` in normal compiles.

```
void destroySpawnersAndItems()
{
    var spawners = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(spawnerItem));
    var items = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(itemFood));

    foreach(var spawner in spawners)
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        DestroyImmediate(spawner.gameObject});
        #else
        Destroy(spawner.gameObject);
        #endif
    }

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        #if UNITY_EDITOR
        DestroyImmediate(item.gameObject});
        #else
        Destroy(item.gameObject);
        #endif
    }
}
```